# jquery plugin to manage cookies

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies, jquery-plugins

I have to create, update, delete, get the cookies in my project for different products. So is there any jquery plugin for this. Now i am using this to mange cookies in my project.

```
  function createCookie(name, value, days) {
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        }
        else var expires = "";
        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
    }
    function readCookie(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
        return null;
    }
    function eraseCookie(name) {
        createCookie(name, "", -1);
    }
```

I need a plugin for this which can also update the previous cookie with new product and their value.

Comment: there are several you can find using the ubiquitous search engine

Comment: it seems the most popular one has moved away from being a jQuery plugin to being a standalone library - sensible decision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several plugins for jQuery cookies. You may try https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie or https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/ or just Google it. and find many other plugins.